# Scoping issue on ng-change function on HTML SELECT in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html-select, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-change

I am trying to implement, in a larger context, exactly what is being done in [**`FIDDLE`**](http://jsfiddle.net/G8S32/2985/), shown here:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <select 
        ng-options="ptoGroup as ptoGroup.classname for ptoGroup in ptoGroupTypes"       
        ng-model="ptoItem" 
        ng-change="ptoUpdateUserQueryForm1()">
    </select>
    {{ptoItem.classname}}
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
//myApp.factory('myService', function() {});

myApp.controller("MyCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.ptoGroupTypes = [ 
      {"classname": 'n1'}, 
      {"classname": 'n2'},
      {"classname": 'n3'}
      ];
  $scope.ptoUpdateUserQueryForm1 = function() {
    console.log("1. new formtype = " + $scope.ptoItem.classname);
  };
});
```

This jsfiddle works great.

In my application, everything works exactly the same way except that inside the **$scope.ptoUpdateUserQueryForm** function, the value of **$scope** seems okay but the value of **$scope.ptoItem** is undefined.

**My HTML**

```
<body   ng-app="cdu_app">
    <div ng-controller="cdu_controller">
        <table>     
            <tr>
                <td>Type</td>
                <td>
                    <select 
                    ng-options="ptoGroup as ptoGroup.classname for ptoGroup in ptoGroupTypes"       
                    ng-model="ptoItem" 
                    ng-change="ptoUpdateUserQueryForm()"></select>
                </td>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ptoItem.classname: </td>
                <td>{{ ptoItem.classname }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

**My Javascript**

```
var cduApp = angular.module("cdu_app", []);
cduApp.controller('cdu_controller', function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.ptoGroupTypes = [ 
            { "classname": "Team" }, 
            { "classname": "Organization" }
    ];

    $scope.ptoUpdateUserQueryForm = function() {
        console.log(" $scope.ptoUpdateUserQueryForm = function()");
        console.log("new form type is: " + $scope.ptoItem.classname);
    };
});
```

I am running with `Angularjs 1.4.8`.

Comment: Your code  works, not getting undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that was a type but the object ptoGroupTypes needs to be as

```
$scope.ptoGroupTypes = [ 
        { "classname": "Team" }, 
        { "classname": "Organization" }
];
```

The closing '}' should be ']'.

Checkout this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/G8S32/2995/). It is working.

Just thought of mentioning I changed the name of app from **cdu_app to myApp** for the sake of Fiddle to work.